# log4j linux issue - log file is empty

Tags: java, linux, logging, log4j

Initial config file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=<%p> %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
```

later its confligured to output logs to runtime-specified location:

```
private static Logger configureLogger(ConflictsCheckerArgs dataModel) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationController.class);

    FileAppender newAppender = new FileAppender();
    newAppender.setFile(new File(dataModel.getOutputPath(), "logs.log").getPath());
    newAppender.setName("logsToFile");
    newAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
    newAppender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
    newAppender.setAppend(true);
    newAppender.activateOptions();

    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(newAppender);

    return logger;
}
```

Problem is, that this file is created, but it's empty. I assume, that in jar's/target  location program does not have write-access and maybe log4j try to do something there and that stops it from working at all. Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem - how to have logs in that log file in place of empty file?

Worth to add is that every other "normal" files, that are meant to be put into output directory, are there and they are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try activating the debug functionality to see what the log4j library is doing internally...

Example:

```
java -Dlog4j.debug ...
```

This will print to System.out helpful information about which file it used to initialize itself, which loggers / appenders got configured etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to do with :

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
```

In your application are you logging errors and warnings yet no output?

try changing it to :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

Comment: That's not the case. WARN scope is larger than info, because it includes all of info scope AND adds warn to it. There is a hierarchy WARN > INFO > ERROR. If you use error, only errors will be log, if you use info, both info and errors, and so on... // On Windows above configuration works fine.

Comment: @dantuch were you able to sort this? I confirmed the order is: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL

Comment: nope, I've made a waorkaround... I created my own, SIMPLE, logger, without anything beside writing a log-message String to a file. No levels, no date format. I my case it was enough. This way I know exactly were the output should be produced, and I know that I have access rights there.